# Do I really need an antivirus for my arch linux machine?

Tags: arch-linux, anti-virus

I have an arch Linux machine and I use it quite often. Moreover, I have a lot of applications even applications from aur, so my question is do I need an antivirus for it?

Comment: Nowadays we'd better speak about anti-malware rather than anti-virus. Genuine virus are just a minor part of the malwares. The two best anti-malware entities are 1) the administrator of the machine, who is in charge of keeping it up-to-date in terms of security patches, and 2) the user, who should think twice before clicking a link in a dubious email or installing a software from a source other than an official editor or the official repository of the distribution.

Comment: I agree. Thete arnt many virii for Linux as its not a popular desktop system,l - however as its a common server architecture the better your security model the better protectrd you will be. In my experience, AV software for Linux is not much of a thing, but can be useful  for finding bad files distributed to Windows and (if running a web server) an indication of hacked websites histed on the Linux box.

Comment: I have somehow answered in a comment, and didn't downvote your question. However, your question is largely opinion-based and could lead to endless discussions because there is actually no definite answer. I gave a hint in my comment, but some other people may disagree and we are all right. This is the kind of question [that is discouraged here](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask), and it could even have been closed.

Comment: Your question would have been better, if for instance you had specified the context of use of the machine (classical mail/surf, multimedia server, open server for third party people on the internet, etc..), your expertise (absolute newbie, poweruser...), the research you made on the topic (this specialized IT site xxx recommends an anti-virus, this other one zzz doesn't recommend, what is the usual practice?)...

Comment: @PierU I use it as my daily driver

Answer (score 0):

It might turn out to be worth it if you:

- use software from outside the repository,
- download suspicious files from the Web,
- and so on.

It's not absolutely necessary, but it's certainly an additional layer of security to have on your computer.

Comment: How do you tell if a file is suspicious?

Comment: using antivirus is the best

Comment: @jastyles Was that a response to my comment? If so, now you have a chicken and egg problem. You don't need an antivirus if you don't download suspicious files, but you need an antivirus to tell if a file is suspicious. Saying you don't need AV if you don't download suspicious files is like saying that you don't need seatbelts unless you're going to have an accident.

Answer (score -1):

Since the AUR isn't vetted, and since you browse the web on this machine, it seems prudent to run antivirus.

Comment: have you read what I have written?